# Minimum edit length of 6 seems rather arbitrary -- prevented me from correcting grammar

Tags: discussion

The poster confused 'whose' (possessive pronoun) with "who's" (contraction for "who is") in two places. I tried to correct the grammatical error but got a message that edits had to be at least 6 characters.

I'm curious how the number 6 was arrived at.

Who's idea was that?  Correction: *Whose* idea was that?

Comment: You should correct more than just a few character. Usually, there are other thing on the post that needs correction.

Comment: I, for one, would have rejected such an edit as Too Minor, unless it fixes other issues in the post.

Comment: @DavidRobinson  What if there are no other issues?

Comment: You're right. Minimum edit length should be 6.5

Comment: @David Robinson:  A spelling error is a spelling error, no more, no less. Opinions on the importance or lack of importance of the error can lead to nothing but disagreement and stalemate. Some people will say that it is very important while others will say it is not important at all. A community site should try to avoid Opinion and stick to Fact.  Having opinions is often a lot more fun than having facts, I admit, so keeping to the facts is easier said than done. But it is a good goal to have.